# Prove that the mean of the $u_i$'s generated by a congruential linear generator of complete period is $\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{2m}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences, random, congruence-relations

Congruential linear generator (pseudo random numbers)
I have to prove this proposition but I don't know how. I tried by induction on $m$, the modulus of the generator, but it hadn't got me anywhere:

> Prove that the mean of the $u_i$'s generated by a congruential linear generator of complete period is $$\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{2m}$$ 
>   where every $u_i = \frac{z_i}{m}$ and $z_i = a^iz_0 + c\frac{(a^i - 1)}{a-1}\mod m$.

This theorem says when is a clg of complete period:

> A clg has complete period if and only if the following three conditions are satisfied:
>
> 1. $c$ and $m$ are relative primes.
> 2. If $q$ is a prime that divides $m$, then $q$ also divides $a-1$.
> 3. If $4$ divides $m$, $4$ divides $a-1$."

Any idea can help me, I'm really lost. Thanks.

Comment: A complete-period LCG is also uniform: It returns every single $z$ from $0$ to $m-1$ exactly once (It can't return the same $z$ more than once in a period $m$ because the output $z$ **is** the state: If a $z$ repeated, so did the state, which means it cycled, so the period was $<m$ and not complete). Therefore, the **sum** of all the $z$ over a period is just the sum of all integers $0$ to $m-1$: $$\sum_i z_i = \frac{(m-1)m}{2} = \frac{m^2 - m}{2}$$ Their **average** $\bar z$ is that sum divided by their number, $m$. And since $u_i = z_i/m$, $$\bar u = \bar z/m = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2m}$$